# NextJs + Nodemailer + Fetch. How to receive a response

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, next.js, nodemailer

I'm building a simple contact form using Next.js, nodemailer and fetch. While the form works and the target email account is receiving the email from the front end form, the contact submission is hanging in the network with a `pending` status. About a minute later, I get a Next.js error reading `Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Failed to fetch`. I have a feeling it has something to do with how I'm using Fetch. I'm used to Axios, and I took this as an opportunity to get better with Fetch. However I referenced [MDN's Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) page.

**Form.js**

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

const Form = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
    const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false)

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let data = {
            name,
            email,
            message
        }

        fetch('/api/contact', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }).then((response) => {
        /// NOT RECEIVING CONSOLE LOG OR RESPONSE STATUS BELOW
            console.log('response recieved')
            if (response.status === 200) {
                console.log('response succeeded')
                setSubmitted(true)
                setName('')
                setEmail('')
                setBody('')
            } 
        }).then(data => {
            console.log(data)
        }).then((error) => {
            console.error(error)
        })
      }          

    return (
        <div >
        < form >
        < formGroup >
            < label htmlFor='name'>Name</label>
            < input type='text' onChange={(e)=>{setName(e.target.value)}} name='name' /> 
        </formGroup>
        < formGroup >
            < label htmlFor='email'>Email</label>
            < input type='text' onChange={(e)=>{setEmail(e.target.value)}} name='email' />
        </formGroup>
        < formGroup >
            < label htmlFor='message'>Message</label>
            < input type='text' onChange={(e)=>{setMessage(e.target.value)}} name='message' />
        </formGroup>
        < input type='submit' onClick={(e)=>{handleSubmit(e)}}/>
        </form >
        </div>
    )
}

export default Form;
```

The fetch above references the contact form below, which is in the `api` folder that comes with a standard Next.js project. Refactored this a few times to see if there was any difference, including async/await.

**contact.js**

```js
export default function (req, res) {
    require('dotenv').config();
    
    let nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
    
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      port: 465,
      host: "smtp.gmail.com",
      auth: {
        user: 'samplenodemailer@email.com',
        pass: process.env.password,
      },
      secure: true,
    })

    const mailData = {
      from: 'samplenodemailer@email.com',
      to: 'targetinbox@email.com',
      subject: `Test Quote Submission From: ${req.body.name}`,
      text: req.body.message + " | Sent from: " + req.body.email,
      html: `<div>${req.body.message}</div><p>Sent from:
      ${req.body.email}</p>`
    }

    transporter.sendMail(mailData, function (err, info) {
      if(err)
        {console.log(err)}
      else
        {console.log(info)}
    })

    res.status(200)
  }
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. I have a feeling it has to do with how I'm handling Fetch in **Form.js**. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**
Here are some relevant logs

Terminal: `API resolved without sending a response for /api/contact, this may result in stalled requests.`

Comment: Try calling [`end()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.end) in your API route: `res.status(200).end()`.

Comment: That did it. Thank you! I've never had to use ```.end()``` even in the backend api's that I've built from scratch. Is there a reason it's needed here?

Comment: `.status()` alone won't send a response by itself.

Comment: I see! So when I'm sending responses in a crud api, I'm always sending something. Whether it be a create/modified object, data for reading, or an  'object deleted' message. In those situations, would it be good practice to use ```.end()``` as well?

Comment: `res.end()` is used to end the response without any data. To respond with data use methods such as `res.send()` and `res.json()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your API route, `res.status(200)` alone won't send a response - you need to call `end()`.

```js
export default function (req, res) {
    //...
    res.status(200).end()
}
```